# How can I output a column from another table when using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

With the syntax below, `t3`(table3) columns are not displayed but I need to get the `page_ID` from the table.. Any help?

```
SELECT t1.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.page_num  separator ', ')pageNR
    FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.pid = t1.pid
JOIN t3 on t3.ID = t1.ID
    WHERE t1.ID = ?
    AND t3.page_num = t2.page_num
    ORDER BY t1.tag
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You have an aggregation function with `select *` but no appropriate `group by`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Move the page_num join condition to the ON clause, to make the code proper.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.page_num separator ', ') as pageNR,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t3.page_id separator ', ') as pageIds
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.pid = t1.pid JOIN
     t3 
     On t3.ID = t1.ID AND t3.page_num = t2.page_num
WHERE t1.ID = ?
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```

Comment: plus 1 - You're fast... ;)  . I hadn't even finished writing my first paragraph.

Comment: Thankyou for replying so fast.
Yet I get Unexpected token errors at 
     `ON t3.pid = t1.pid AND t3.page_num = t2.page_num`

Comment: @veskimati . . . That expression is not in this answer.  But you should adjust the column names to match your actual data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, my bad. I meant Unexpected token errors at **row 8: On t3.ID = t1.ID AND t3.page_num = t2.page_num** I did replace all tables & column names to originals, checked 10 times and don't have a clue why I get these errors. For some reason, all tokens on row 8 are unexpected